# Cursor in application window not correct type

Tags: c++, winapi, cursor

After messing around a little with making a GUI with the Windows API, I recently realized a problem with the cursor.  When I compile and run my application, it shows a window like its supposed to.  When I drag my cursor from the left side of my screen into my applications window, as it goes over the border it becomes the <-> thing for resizing but it remains like that anywhere inside my window.  Same goes for if I bring it into the window from the bottom.  The problem does not exist when I do from the right side though.  I questioned if it was just my program so I went to the MSDN website and even compiled and tried their program (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381409%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  Same Problem! So then I started experimenting with the WM_SETCURSOR message and cursor functions but got nowhere.
Does anyone have any explanation to this and what I could do to fix it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that example code will behave as you describe because the `hCursor` member of `WNDCLASS` is set to zero, and `WindowProc()` doesn't handle `WM_SETCURSOR`.

If you want the same cursor all the time then it's easiest to do something like this when setting up your window class:

```
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
```

If you want to have more control over the cursor then you want to leave `WNDCLASS::hCursor` zero and call `SetCursor()` in response to `WM_SETCURSOR`.  You'll need to load/create your various cursors, and have some way of choosing the appropriate one based on your application's state.

Comment: Yes!, I should have read the documentation more closely for loadcursor function because I did have the first parameter my instance when loading an arrow provided by the OS.  Problem Solved, Thanks.